# YouTube Data API V3 quota increase

Tags: youtube-data-api

If I set up a billing account on GCP, do I get unlimited API requests with any quota limit? I'm trying to fetch all the videos of some channels and it's throwing an error with the code 403: quota exhausted.

As of now, it's limited for 10,000 requests per day. Please help.

Comment: Billing and quota increase aren't related, cf https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota By the way, what endpoints of YouTube Data API v3 are you using?